# how to form a array of changed values in a form using ng change

Tags: angularjs, arrays, function

If I have a form with 3 fields how can I get an array of  only the changed values using ng-change while I submit the form.

```
<form name="myForm">
<input name="myInput" ng-model="myInput" type="text" ng-change="fn">
<input name="email" ng-model="email" type="email" ng-change="fn">

</form>
```

Comment: write a method for that , whats is the issue.

Comment: can you please elaborate your question? Give an example for it.

Comment: I need an array of the input field values which I modified if I did not modify an input field I don't want its value in the array

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use ng-submit in your form to get value on submit? somthing like this:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="myFunction()">
<input name="myInput" ng-model="myInput" type="text" >
<input name="email" ng-model="email" type="email" >

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

In HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="submit()">
    <input name="myInput" ng-model="myInput" type="text" >
    <input name="email" ng-model="email" type="email" >
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
{{ud}}
```

In controller:

```
$scope.ud = [];
$scope.submit = function() {
    var elems = document.forms["myForm"].getElementsByTagName("input");
    console.log(elems)
    for(var i=0; i<elems.length;i++) {
      if(elems[i].value) {
        console.log(elems[i])
        $scope.ud.push(elems[i].value)
      }
    }
  }
```

This will solve your problem.

All the best.